# jquery accordion remains selected after closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got a jQuery sortable accordion. When I hover my mouse over each of the accordion headers, they all appropriately switch to the highlighted/selected color state. When I click on a header to open that portion of the accordion and then click it again to close that portion of the accordion, the highlighted/selected color state remains.

So if I've got 10 sections to the accordion, then I open and close 3 of them, those 3 are colored differently than the rest of the accordion. That provides a bad UI. Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

EDIT:

Sorry about not providing an example to start, I'm working under an NDA so I can't provide them directly. I put together an sharable example of what is happening though.

You can see it happen here: http://inadaydevelopment.com/StackOverflow/AccordionStateProblem/jqueryexample.html

If you hover over them, they change to orange (correct). If you click on one to open it up, it remains orange (correct). If you close it and no longer hover, it still remains orange instead of going back to blue (wrong).

Comment: can't help fix what can't be seen... numerous script,css and html variations for an accordon

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nDEHb/1/  tell me if this has your problem

Comment: Sorry about not providing an example to start, I'm working under an NDA so I can't provide them directly. I put together an sharable example of what is happening though. I've added it to my question above, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will clear the "ui-state-focus" class that is causing the issue:

```
$('.ui-accordion .group > h3').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus')
})
```

This was tested in browser console against the demo.

EDIT: selector could simply be narrowed down to:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header')
```